# How to pass parameters to Microsoft SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

I am new to SQL Server 2012, and I found SQL Server Management Studio is a little bit difficult to use.

Here is one of the problems that I cannot solve: Is it possible to pass values to a query in SQL Server Management Studio ?

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table           
WHERE col3 = :variable
```

If I run this query in the Studio, instead of prompting an input field to let me input value for *variable*, it will not execute the query because of an error

> Incorrect syntax near ':'

I used to use the same method in SQL Developer for Oracle, thus I thought it would work the same.

Thanks for any useful advice.

Comment: Those are **two totally separate, different tools** - you cannot just assume that what works in SQL Developer will work in SQL Server Mgmt Studio ......

Comment: @marc_s Yes, you are right. It seems I need time to get used to the new Tool. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @someVariable varchar(n)
SET @someVariable = 'variable'

SELECT col1, col2
FROM table           
WHERE col3 = someVariable
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems the right answer. Actually I searched and found this method before I asking the question. The problem was I could not break my mind-set: I wrongly expected the parameters should be input after running the query.